# how to add search_fields in django forms

Tags: django, search, django-forms

I was making a django forms and there is a field owner which is related with ForeignKey by User model , Sometimes name of user is same so I want to search it by their email address , How can I add searching of email field in forms like this search_fields = ['email'].

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ('name', 'owner', 'club', 'moderator', 'group_type', 'country')

def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
    # brand = kwargs.pop("brand")
    super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    language_results = User.objects.all()
    # self.fields["owner"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    # self.fields["owner"].widget = autocomplete.ModelSelect2()
    self.fields["owner"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'placeholder': "Choose the users(s)",
        'class': 'chzn-select',
        'multiple tabindex': '6',
    }))
```

Comment: Basically a search field is a `CharField` in your form and you can process the search logic in a View or use [Elastic Search](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl)

Answer (score 0):

you just use a CharField and add that form in your template;and after submiting that search you get the value entred by the user and use the objects filter to return the corresponding result.